# Fixed width flat file import mongodb

Tags: mongodb, fixed-width

How can I import a Fixed Width flat file with delimiters to MongoDB. Along with that maintain the Width (document size for the specific field) not be updated beyond a specific size or characters. Also, is it possible for me to check the size of each document that will be inserted or update and lock it at a specific size.

This looks like old style requirement. I tried to avoid this with client validation, but could not? Any help

I know that i can use Object.bsonsize to get the size of the document matched. But, to limit it is a question i would like to know?